# Community users unable to upload profile picture

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, community-builder

While trying to change the profile picture logged in as any Community Client user, the community page returns the following error message: "We can't upload your photo right now. Please wait a few minutes and try again."

I saw that this file upload component sends a request through Chatter:

```
https://...sandbox.my.site.com/_ui/core/chatter/photos/PhotoUploadServlet?recordId=...
```

This is the same format of request sent while changing the image of a user through the regular user detail record page in Lightning. My guess is that these users are not able to access Chatter and that's the reason why they're not allowed to change their profile picture from the community site.

In this case, is there any workaround to let users update their profile pictures (maybe a custom component) or the only way to do it is on the main org through the user details record page?

Comment: If you are using classic there is known issue kindly switch to lightning and see if that works (https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000yyrChAAI/~)